# How to add fadeIn() method for each object in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an Iframe whose source changes every 5 seconds:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  if (typeof $('.frame') != 'undefined' || null) {
    $(".frame").ready(function() {
      var locations = ['http://www.webstarts.com/support/2011/03/how-to-add-an-iframe-to-your-webstarts-website/', 'http://www.wix.com/app-market/html-iframe-embed/overview',
        'http://codepen.io/jmelgoza/pen/jEaGYg',
        'http://www.oddee.com/item_96986.aspx',
        'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2488496/',
        'http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp'
      ];
      var len = locations.length;
      var iframe = $('.frame');
      var i = 0;
      setInterval(function() {
        iframe.attr('src', locations[++i % len]);
      }, 5000);
    });
  }
});
```

I would like to have it so that every time the source changes there is a fadeIn/fadeOut effect. How would I go about doing this? Currently the source is switching but it kind of pops in and out between the sources abruptly. I would like to have a more elegant transition between the sources when they switch. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: FYI, `$(".frame").ready(...);` is not what you think it is...

Comment: What do I think it is? What would you do instead (in this situation) or what would be better?

Comment: There is no ready event for iframe

Comment: Thanks for the input. I changed it to document. Out of curiousity, do you think the typeof $('.frame') != 'undefined' || null) is necessary? I am reading a few comments and it seems there are issues with it (even though the code works with it).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    iframe.attr('src', locations[++i % len]);
    iframe.fadeOut(300, function() {
        iframe.fadeIn(300);
    });
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using something like this:

```js
  setInterval(function () {
                iframe.attr('src', locations[++i % len]);
                iframe.fadeOut(300, function () {
                    iframe.fadeIn(300);
                });
```

and replaced the current interval function. I would have also 'up voted' whoever recommended this to me but I no longer see their post. Also if there are anymore recommendations as to how I should improve this code (even though it seems to be working) I am listening. I am sure it can be better.

Comment: I undeleted my answer you're referring to.

Answer (score -1):

I can update this answer as more issues with the code become relevant, but the first thing that stands out is this line:

```
if (typeof $('.frame') != 'undefined' || null) {
```

I think what you're looking for here is this for your defensive programming technique:

```
if ($('.frame') != null && $('.frame').length > 0) {
```

Comment: `$('.frame')` will always be a jQuery object. It will never be the undefined type, the string undefined or null.

Comment: That's true.  Updated.  Technically, then you could probably just do `$('.frame').length > 0` but I still like keeping the `$('.frame') != null`.